# Ubuntu does not boot after LAMP install

Tags: dual-boot, apache2

After following the suggestions of my friends I have finally decided to use ubuntu.
I downloaded the windows installer and installation was really a breeze.

However what followed was a disaster. I used

```
sudo tasksel
```

to install LAMP and everything completed successfully but when I tried to reboot Ubuntu the system does not boot anymore it goes to a screen which reads somehow like

"using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName .. the server's fully qualified domain [OK]
*starting web server apache 2"

(I dont have enough reputation to post the screenshot)

And from there I cannot do anything. So what should I do now?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version did you install? I may be wrong, but I believe the Ubuntu Windows Installer was discontinued

Comment: 12.0.4 downloaded from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows

Answer (score 0):

The server booted, just the `apache` got stuck somewhere. Log in and check the `/var/log/apache2/error-log` file's content, you will have the answer about what was wrong.

Comment: I just said that I cannot boot? How can I login and check the error-log?

Comment: Can you log in at one of the virtual terminals (e.g. using the Ctrl-Alt-F2 key combo)?

Comment: @steeldriver thnx actually this way I was able to login but event after completely uninstalling LAMP packages I still cant get into the desktop. During tasksel LAMP install I removed some pre-selected options and maybe this caused the error?